# i got this error again and again ,please tell me why

Tags: python

i am creating a txt file in juypternotebook

```
%%writefile test.txt
hello this is my first line
hello this is my second line
```

after that when i am appending some lines in that txt file by writing the code

```
with open ('test.txt' ,mode = 'r') as f:
```

then this error appears

```
File "<ipython-input-9-e008d94f1356>", line 1
    with open ('test.txt' ,mode = 'r') as f:
                                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

please tell me why

Comment: Are you forgetting to close a parenthesis, apostrophe or something maybe?

Comment: There should not be space use this: with open('test.txt' ,mode = 'r') as f:

Comment: @KhakharShyam space before the `(` is ignored.

Comment: Is that your whole script? You need some code inside the `for` loop.

Comment: If you want to append to the file, you need to open it in `a` mode. `r` is for reading the file.

Comment: Please update the whole code so tat we can check

Comment: @KhakharShyam It looks like that *is* the whole code. The error message says it's line 1, so there's nothing before it. And it's getting an EOF error, so it must be the end of the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can't start a `with` statement (or any block) and just end the script there, the block needs at least one command in it.

If you don't want to add the commands yet, use `pass` as a placeholder.

```
with open ('test.txt' ,mode = 'r') as f:
    pass
```

Comment: Maybe OP changed his question, but i don't see a for-loop here?

Comment: Right, I meant to say "with" statement. It probably applies to any type of block